# wxPython App.MainLoop not working in while loop

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm using wxPython and I'm pretty new to it. My main program runs like so

```
app = wx.App(False)

While True:
    -> do stuff like create and modify wx frames, get them to show
    -> do other stuff important for my program

    app.MainLoop()
```

The problem is when I run app.MainLoop(), my While True loop stops! I am very new to wxPython and don't really understand how it all works, so I'm not sure what to do. I need to do a bunch of stuff in my While loop, but if I don't call app.MainLoop() inside the While Loop (i.e. call it before), the wx frames dont appear properly. But if I call app.MainLoop() inside the While True loop, my while loop stops. How can I make this so that my While True loop won't stop executing?

Thanks

Comment: The stuff to do must be done in a separate thread. WxPython occupies the main thread with its loop. Be aware that you can't call most wxPython functions from a separate thread. If you have to visually show something from the stuff you do you must call `wx.CallAfter` in the other thread which will then call the given function in the main thread.

Comment: `While True` is endless, what if you just drop the `While`, do what you need, then `app.MainLoop()`.

Comment: ok thanks. I think I'll use Timer to create a separate thread, and instead of a while loop I'll just have a function that calls itself over and over on a separate thread